# Load CLOB into Column from Local File (not oracle server)

Tags: oracle, clob

I would like to load a txt file into a CLOB field.  The catch is that the file resides on the local disk (not on the oracle server).  Is it possible to do this with pl/sql, running windows, perhaps from from TOAD or SQLPlus?

If so, could someone share the pl/sql?

I have seen several posts on loading a CLOB File from the server disk, [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169996/storing-files-in-oracle-dbs-clob-field) and [Example2](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/LOBs/LOBS_41.shtml).  But can't seem to find anything on loading the file from **local disk**.

Thank you!

ps, It would be great if the routine supported multi-byte text (as in the examples).

Comment: PL/SQL executes in the server context.  It does not have any "access" to a client's local machine.  You can certainly use TOAD to edit a CLOB field, but that is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use a PL/SQL script to load a local file into table. But there is an alternative: loading local file(s) into CLOB field with *local* Oracle SQL*Loader. Install Oracle Client on your machine if you didn't do this before and use [the article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/load-lob-data-using-sql-loader.php) to create your own SQL*Loader config and script to running it.

Comment: Thank you for the link, unfortunately SQL*Loader won't work here.  I am looking to update a CLOB column, within an existing table, not the entire row.

Comment: Hum, you can create some staging table that will store a row with CLOB data until you update a field within your table. After that you could clean the staging table.

Comment: SQL-script that calls shell script,  which set environment variables and load a local file into the staging table, then updates your data and clean staging table -- all this may looks little complicated... But it will work.

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed sound rather complicated, but it does also sound like something that could work.  Not sure which environment variables you're referring to.  But, it sounds like it has at least three pieces, shell script to set env vars, PL/SQL routine to load the data to temp table, pl/sql routine to push CLOB field to destination table, right?    I wonder if you could provide an example?