# "unknown command" for dbms_lob.open command in Sql+

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am a total beginner when it comes to PL/SQL and Sql+. I am trying to write a function that will extract the contents of a text file into a CLOB (following [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169996/storing-files-in-oracle-dbs-clob-field) as an example). When I issue the following command in Sql+:

```
dbms_lob.open( 'c:\temp\test.txt', dbms_lob.lob_readonly );
```

I get the following error message:

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "dbms_lob.o..." - rest of line ignored.
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax of the command, or something else entirely?

Thanks much!

Comment: Stored procedures are run using the `execute` command. More details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm#i2697931

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in oracle. For me the problem is that for launch this command in sqlplus you may declare an anonymous block like this:

```
DECLARE
-- variables
BEGIN
    --- your commands here
    dbms_lob.open......
END;
```

To launch the execution you have to digit / and then return

Comment: `execute dbms_lob.open(...)` is completely enough.

Comment: Tried `execute...` and went farther than before but got `PLS-00363: expression 'c:\temp\badOCR02.txt' cannot be used as an assignment target`. Is this related to how this is invoked or is something else wrong? Thx